# Symfony 3 Reset password by username/email

Tags: symfony, token, reset-password

I am trying to create a password reset form based on the value of email, but if I enter my email and click send, my page refreshes only instead of sending an email to the address entered in the form field, so that the user retrieves the password change link.
I would like an email to be sent to the address mentioned with a link to allow the user to change his password.

**Controller**

```
 public function requestPassAction(Request $request)
{

       $tmpUser = new User();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $form = $this->createForm('Doctix\UserBundle\Form\ForgottenUserType', $tmpUser);
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 



        $user = $em->getRepository('DoctixUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(['username'=>$tmpUser->getUsername()]);
    if($user)
        {
          if ($user->getToken() === null  ) {
                /** @var $tokenGenerator TokenGeneratorInterface */
                $token = md5(uniqid($user->getUsername(), true)); //some unique token (you can create a nicer token generator in standalone class with a service)
                $user->setToken($token);
                $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                $this->addFlash('Info', 'Si l utilisateur est trouvé, vous allez recevoir un mail avec des instructions.');
    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
                $message = (new \Swift_Message('Renouvellement du mot de passe'))
                        ->setFrom("medmamtest@gmail.com")
                        ->setTo($user->getUsername())
                        ->setBody(
                                $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                                    'Resetting/request.html.twig',
                                    array('user' => $user)
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

                $mailer->send($message);
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Un mail va vous être envoyé afin que vous puissiez renouveller votre mot de passe. Le lien que vous recevrez sera valide 24h.");

                return $this->redirectToRoute("login");
           } 
       }

       else {
              return $this->redirectToRoute("request_resetting") ;
       } 
    }
    return $this->render('Resetting/request.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

**View**

```
   {% extends "DoctixFrontBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
  {% block body %}

<div class="bg_color_2">
    <div class="container margin_60_35">

            <div class="row">

            <div id="login">


  <h1>Mot de passe oublié ?</h1>
  <p>Réinitialiser votre mot de passe en renseignant votre mail.</p>

{{form_start(form)}}
 {{form_widget(form.username)}}
 {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
{{form_end(form)}}


        </div>
        </div>

 </div>
 </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

**Swiftmailer Config**

```
  # Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
   transport: "%mailer_transport%"
   auth_mode: "%mailer_auth_mode%"
   host:      "%mailer_host%"
  encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
  port:      "%mailer_port%"
  username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

Thanks !

Comment: You are spoofing the from address?  How do you know the email is not getting sent, but instead being spam filtered or rejected by the mail server?   Do you have a way of debugging what your MTA is doing?

Comment: @gview, I know the mail is not sent because the symfony toolbar tells me whether or not there is sending mail.And there it tells me that there is no mail sent

Comment: What is the config for swiftmailer?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrauze, 
I already used swiftmailer to send mails in other cases in my project and it works.But there at the click of the button send no action is triggered. But I've update my post in adding the config for swiftmailer

Comment: IMHO If your swiftmailer configuration lets you send an email you should try to check your logic. Did you debug if your code goes into conditions blocks in if($user) and if($user->getToken()) ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrauze, Yeah, i think too that the problem is coming from my code.But how to debug my two conditions blocks ? I think my logic about my test conditions are right, but I can not find the part of the code where that bug